# Finding frequency of a three-phase generator from phase voltages

Tags: three-phase, frequency-measurement

I'm trying to find frequency (i.e.; rotations per second) of a balanced three phase generator. Output peak voltage of the generator goes up to 150V.

One solution I found is to attenuate rectified and filtered versions of this AC by voltage divider resistor network (R<sub>a</sub>, R<sub>b</sub>, R<sub>c</sub> and R<sub>d</sub>), so that the rectified one swings over the filtered one, and then input them to a comparator to find the frequency data.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Note: There is already a bridge rectifier in my circuit for other purposes, and the GND is taken from it as it is seen in the image below. I can't afford changing GND position at this design level.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the generator gives balanced 3-phase, you can use three large same resistors witch give you the neutral point and then find the frequency from neutral point and one of phases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy76bD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the previous schematic we divided the \$100M\Omega\$ resistor into \$3M\Omega\$ and \$97M\Omega\$ to reduce the output voltage. By the generator's peak voltage (\$150V\$) the output on \$3M\Omega\$ voltage will have less than \$5V\$ peak and can be determined easily by an Op-Amp.

**Another way:**

Of course it is possible to find out frequency of generator from voltage of one line to another. For example from \$R\$ to \$S\$.

The waveform of \$R-S\$ voltage is like this:
[image]

This is the plot of \$f = Sin(x)-Sin(x-2 \pi / 3)\$ (Plotted by [Fooplot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJzaW4oeCktc2luKHgtMipwaS8zKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwfV0-)). The period of f witch can be found by finding the \$f(x)=f(x + T)\$ is same as \$Sin(x)\$. So The frequency of generator is also can be determined by \$l-l\$ voltage. And a simple [zero crossing detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_crossing_detector#Zero_level_detector) can help to find the frequency.

Comment: I am removing your edits to my answer because they are unnecessary. If you feel you need to provide more information add the edits to your post.

Comment: how does this idea allow the OP to have a clean signal representative of the power AC waveform referenced to the negative side of his bridge rectifier?  I think you also need to point out that there is a safety issue with this method because there is no inherent isolation of the signal and this could be dangerous.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks. I added the waveform of L-L and safety to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just attenuate the voltage on one pair of wires and feed it into an opto-isolator like this: -

[image]

This picture was taken from [here](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/5989-0802EN) and the major benefit of using an opto isolator/coupler is that you don't have to have your electronics directly connected to potentially lethal AC voltages. This makes them safe to work on and easier to get working as a prototype.

And if you really want to do it via a bridge rectifier [here](http://www.dextrel.net/diyzerocrosser.htm) is a site that has a schematic: -

[image]

Comment: @Passerby - the edits you approved were not needed and I have removed them

Comment: @Rev1.0 - the edits you approved were not needed and I have removed them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I first decided to directly compare voltage levels of any two different phases with the simple circuit above. In order to see what would happen, I simulated the scenario to see the voltage levels.

[image]
Red: Waveform of R with respect to GND.
Magenta: Waveform of S with respect to GND.

It looks OK. But there is a moment at which both the phase voltages become zero with respect to the GND. It is not clear what would happen at this moment; any noise at opamp input may count as dozens of generator frequency. I gave it a second though and decided to compare one of the phases with average of other two.

[image]
Note: C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> are for noise prevention, because of high resistor values.

In this case, the waveforms of \$V_R\$ and \$\dfrac{V_S + V_T}{2}\$ are as seen in the plotting below.

[image]

Now there is no indefinite region or moment when comparing signal levels. I am going to implement my circuit like this. I hope it works OK.

(Note: Dimensions of the images of the plottings are big enough; just open them in a new tab to see the details and read the texts on them.)

MATLAB code for generating these plottings:

```
V_PEAK          = 200.0;
FREQ            = 100;
PERIOD          = 1 / FREQ;
TMIN            = 0.0;
TMAX            = 3 * PERIOD;
VMIN            = -V_PEAK - 10.0;
VMAX            = +V_PEAK * sqrt(3) + 10.0;
POINTS_PER      = 100000;
POINTS          = (TMAX - TMIN) * POINTS_PER;
PHASE_000       =   0 * pi / 180;
PHASE_120       = 120 * pi / 180;
PHASE_240       = 240 * pi / 180;

t               = linspace(TMIN, TMAX, POINTS);
V000            = zeros(1, POINTS);
V120            = zeros(1, POINTS);
V240            = zeros(1, POINTS);
VDC             = zeros(1, POINTS);
VLINE000        = zeros(1, POINTS);
VLINE120        = zeros(1, POINTS);
VLINE240        = zeros(1, POINTS);

for i = 1 : 1 : POINTS
    V000(i) = V_PEAK * sin(2*pi*FREQ*t(i) - PHASE_000);
    V120(i) = V_PEAK * sin(2*pi*FREQ*t(i) - PHASE_120);
    V240(i) = V_PEAK * sin(2*pi*FREQ*t(i) - PHASE_240);
    if      ((V000(i) > V120(i)) && (V000(i) > V240(i)))
        Vmax = V000(i);
    elseif  ((V120(i) > V000(i)) && (V120(i) > V240(i)))
        Vmax = V120(i);
    else
        Vmax = V240(i);
    end;
    if      ((V000(i) < V120(i)) && (V000(i) < V240(i)))
        Vmin = V000(i);
    elseif  ((V120(i) < V000(i)) && (V120(i) < V240(i)))
        Vmin = V120(i);
    else
        Vmin = V240(i);
    end;
    VDC(i)      = Vmax - Vmin;
    VLINE000(i) = V000(i) - Vmin;
    VLINE120(i) = V120(i) - Vmin;
    VLINE240(i) = V240(i) - Vmin;
end;

close all;
hFig = figure;
hold on;
set(hFig, 'Position', [1200 50 700 950]);
plot(t, V000, 'Color', [0, 0, 1]);
plot(t, V120, 'Color', [0, 1, 0]);
plot(t, V240, 'Color', [0, 1, 1]);
plot(t, VDC,  'Color', [0, 0, 0]);
plot(t, VLINE000, 'Color', [1, 0, 0]);
plot(t, (VLINE120 + VLINE240) ./ 2, 'Color', [1, 0, 1]);
xlim([TMIN, TMAX]);
ylim([VMIN, VMAX]);
```

Comment: Would you mind explain why did you compare the R and S?

Comment: I didn't compare R and S. I copared R and (S+T)/2 (not exactly but close to their average). Because, this method seemed to be a good solution to me. Did you check the plottings? In your method, the neutral point is obtained by very high resistor values; sensing voltage from high impedance source gave me some worries.